# Как создать поисковик в php?

Tags: php, mysql

Пример написания php кода для поиска в MySQL и вывода информации на веб страницу.

Comment: а где пример?ошибка в чем?

Answer (score 2):

Нагугливается на раз-два.

- http://www.designplace.org/scripts.php?page=1&c_id=25
- http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/php-mysql-search-script
- http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_search.htm

Отвечать подробно не на что. Неизвестно — структурирована информация или нет, нужен ли полнотекстовый поиск, нужны ли словоформы, нужен ли поиск по метаданным и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить использовать в запросе оператор LIKE и выполнять поиск по шаблону.
[вот инфа](http://www.ageent.ru/sql-like.html)

Answer (score 0):

Не, mysql для поискового сайта никак не подойдет. Если ресурсы позволяют, т.е. сайт находится на vps/vds, то нужно ставить sphinx например, он создан для быстрого поиска.